# Canon MB2320: Scangear works, but simplescan and xsane don't find scanner

Tags: drivers, canon, scanner

The title pretty much says it all.  Picked the Canon MB2320 largely because it came with Linux drivers, and I have to say that installing it was a snap.  So was installing the Canon scanner utility 'scangearmp2'.  This utility finds the scanner and works OK.

But neither simplescan nor xsane can find the scanner.  Can anyone suggest an approach to get these programs to recognize the scanner?

Comment: For anyone who finds this question in the future, [this works](http://askubuntu.com/questions/641261/how-can-i-link-my-canon-mg5650-scanner-to-ubuntu)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canon does not develop SANE drivers for their scanners but they provide an own solution `scangearmp` for basic scan functions. This will of course not allow using SANE backends such as `simplescan` or `xsane`.

For many PIXMA scanners there is a SANE implementation [sane-pixma](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sane-pixma) but I could not test if these work or can be made working with the Canon MAXIFY series.

It appears that the MAXIFY series of scanners are [not yet supported by SANE](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-CANON). Therefore we will have to use the proprietary Canon application until somebody develops a SANE driver for them.