# How can I link my Canon MG5650 scanner to Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, scanner

I have a multi-purpose printer (scanner/printer/copier) Canon MG5650. I can now print wirelessly, how can I add it as a scanner to Ubuntu?

Comment: look at this: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/canon-driver-scangear-mp-ubuntu-14-04/  they have listed some MG5XXX series models as supported...

Answer (score 8):

You need nightly version of sane. You can compile it yourself or install it from this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git

You can add this repository and upgrade sane this way (in terminal):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rolfbensch/sane-git
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You might need to do `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix some dependency problems.

If you don’t have `sane` already installed, you can do this after adding this PPA by:

```
sudo apt-get install xsane sane
```

I have the same printer/scanner, and after installing nightly sane from this repository, I could easily use the scanner. When connected to the same network that the scanner is connected to, just run `xsane` (you should be able to find in applications menu) and let it discover your device from network.

You’ll also be able to use other `sane`-based tools for scanning, like `xscanimage`, `skanlite` etc. (even LibreOffice, you can find list of them here: http://www.sane-project.org/sane-frontends.html).

Your all-in-one device should be visible in titlebar of those programs as `pixma:MG5600_<ip_address>`.

Oh, and most of those tools allow you to scan in 1200 dpi resolution. **Don’t** use it, the scanner is capable of maximum 600 dpi, anything greater will lead you to scrambled image acquired.

Comment: You might need `scangearmp` as well to find the scanner because xsane alone won't always do.

Comment: Just running "sudo apt-get install xsane sane" worked for me, no need for the nightly build.